# Как на python записать строку байт в двоичном виде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в консоли пайтон ввести строку 00000110001110001 так чтобы она считалась двумя байтами. Таких строк очень много.

Comment: Напишите в вопросе пример данных и что получится

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы биты, записанные как текст "01" с помощью цифр в двоичной системе, превратить в байты:

```
>>> bits = '00000110001110001'
>>> int(bits, 2).to_bytes((len(bits.lstrip('0')) + 7) // 8, 'big')
b'\x0cq'
```

Если ведущие нули имеют значение, то уберите `lstrip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(encoding, errors), 'big'))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))


def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0'


print(text_to_bits('kolya'))        

print(text_from_bits('0110101101101111011011000111100101100001'))
```

Comment: если чужой код копируете,  то источник указывайте. Не следует чужой код за свой выдавать. [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Comment: @jfs Забыл извиняюсь